# ajax form in CodeIgniter - sending generated form

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to open a modal and get the content (the formular) form the controller. These steps work fine.

Now I have the formular inside the modal. How I can submit these formular and process it with the same controller function?

At the Moment I do the Ajax-Call in this way

```
$('.modaldisconnect').click(function(){
                var modid = $(this).attr('modid');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/module/disconnect_form",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {modid:modid},
                    // Callback function that is executed after data is successfully sent and received
                    success: function(data){
                     // Print the fetched data of the selected phone in the section called #phone_result 
                     // within the Bootstrap modal
                        $('.modal-ajax-content').html(data);
                        // Display the Bootstrap modal
                        $('#disconnect_modal').modal('show');
                    },
                        error: function(error){
                        // Show error message
                        alert('error');
                            }
             });
            });
```

This is the form which will be generate from the controller by the call above

```
echo'   <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modul_disc_infos">
                    <span class="module-headlines-title">'._l("modul_name").': <span id="disc_modulname">'._l('module_'.$result->folder.'_titel').'</span></span>
                    <span class="module-headlines-subtitle">'._l("modul_disconnect_deadline").': <span id="disc_enddate">'.$enddate.'</span></span>                 
                </div>
                <div id="modul_disc_check">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'._l("modul_disconnect_disclaimer").'</div>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check_disclaimer" value="1"> '._l("modul_disconnect_disclaimer_check").'   
                    <input type="hidden" name="modid" value="'.$this->input->post('modid').'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="formstep" value="1">                 
                    '.$errormsg.'               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">'._l('close').'</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="submit_disconnect" >'._l('modul_disconnect_now').'</button>
            </div>';
```

By the way - is there a better way to parse the values of the formular instead one by one like in my code "var modid = $(this).attr('modid');"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved that in this way that i do 2 different ajax call, starts with a click or submit on the form or a specific button. One call generate the form, one call handle the form. For me it works and its a little bit flexibel to use the same functions for different jobs.

```
//Formular for disconnection
            $('.modaldisconnect').click(function(){
                var modid = $(this).attr('modid');
                $('#ajax_modal_title').html('<?php echo _l('modul_disconnect'); ?>');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/module/disconnect_form",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {modid:modid},
                    // Callback function that is executed after data is successfully sent and recieved
                    success: function(data){
                     // Print the fetched data of the selected phone in the section called #phone_result 
                     // within the Bootstrap modal
                        $('.modal-ajax-content').html(data);
                        // Display the Bootstrap modal
                        $('#ajax_modal').modal('show');
                    },
                        error: function(error){
                        // Show error message
                        alert('error');
                            }
             });
            });

      //Handle the disconnection  
        $("#ajax_form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        subform=$('input[name="subform"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/module/"+subform+"_form",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(), 
            success: function(result){
                $('.modal-ajax-content').html(result);
            },
                        error: function(error){
                        // Show error message
                        alert('error');
                            }
        });
    });
```